# How do I link spreadsheets to share limited data with others?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a master file in Google Docs and want to share some, but not all of the data with others; they need to sort the data I link them to.  How do I link the docs so changes to the master are reflected in the second?

Answer (score 1):

create a new spreadsheet and use **`=IMPORTRANGE("url-of-your-sheet"; A1:Z)`**

and then you can **`=QUERY`** / **`=FILTER`** all necessary data for them